# Reject or filter requests in wsgi

Tags: python, django, wsgi

Is there a  way to reject or filter incoming requests in WSGI? I'd like to reject all requests with extensions like .asp, .php, .mdb, .ini, etc.  I've done some looking and haven't found a good example or if it's possible.  Any suggestions or resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to check every request and then do what you like with them before them reach your `urls` or `views`.

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

Comment: I've thought about that.  I'm wondering if its more efficient to catch before it hits the middleware

Comment: @user4107395 Then I think you should do it in the web server like nginx or apache before it hit django

Comment: PaaS (pythonanywhere) only provides access to wsgi .... or at least all I can find.